# How to configure a module in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jackrabbit

I have deployed Jackrabbit as a module. It is the JCA version. I am very confused on how to actually configure this, and even if I can do that?

Is it possible to reference this installed module and then configure it? Or am I all wrong about the concept? I have attached to images of what I have done.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation :
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JackrabbitDeploymentInAS6AndAS7
Basically the rar is to be deployed through the console.

Comment: Yes, but why do I have to install it as a module and then deploy it again?